# ContainsKey of HashMap does not work with a Custom Class as key

Tags: java, hashmap, key, equals, hashcode

I have a custom class MarioState that I want to use in a HashMap. The class represents a possible state in a state space of the Mario game. Below is a simplified version of the class MarioState.

In my HashMap I want to store these states. However, not ever property in the MarioState is something that should be considered when comparing two MarioState's. For example if one MarioState has the stuck property set to true and a distance of 30 and another MarioState also has the stuck property set to true but a different distance value (e.g. 20) then they still should be considered the same.

I know for this to work in my HashMap I have to implement the .equals() and .hashcode() methods, which is what I did (by letting them be automatically generated by the InteliJ IDE).

```
public class MarioState{

    // Tracking the distance Mario has moved.
    private int distance;
    private int lastDistance;

    // To keep track of if Mario is stuck or not.
    private int stuckCount;
    private boolean stuck;

    public MarioState(){
        stuckCount = 0;
        stuck = false;

        distance = 0;
        lastDistance = 0;
    }

    public void update(Environment environment){

        // Computing the distance
        int tempDistance = environment.getEvaluationInfo().distancePassedPhys;
        distance = tempDistance - lastDistance;
        lastDistance = tempDistance;

        // If Mario hasn't moved for over 25 turns then this means he is stuck.
        if(distance == 0){
            stuckCount++;
        } else {
            stuckCount = 0;
            stuck = false;
        }

        if(stuckCount > 25){ stuck = true; }
    }

    public float calculateReward(){
        float reward = 0f;
        reward += distance * 2;
        if(stuck){ reward += -20; }
        return reward;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MarioState that = (MarioState) o;

        if (stuck != that.stuck) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (stuck ? 1 : 0);
    }  
}
```

The problem is however that when running the code some of the keys are considered different when it shouldn't be according to their .equals() and .hashcode() functions. What can possibly cause this? Did I forget something?

The code used when inserting states in the HashMap (additional information can be provided if necessary):

```
public float[] getActionsQValues(MarioState state){
    if(!table.containsKey(state)) {
        float[] initialQvalues = getInitialQvalues(state);
        table.put(state, initialQvalues);
        return initialQvalues;
    }
    return table.get(state);
}
```

A screenshot when I'm in debug mode shows my table containing two keys with different values, but the keys itself are the same (but in the HashMap it is considered different).

[image: Screenshot of Debug Mode]

Comment: Are you by any chance changing `stuck` *after* adding the element to the map? That would definitely explain it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Short answer: yes. Long Answer: I have another class keeping track of the current state as a variable. Every timestep the update method is called from the MarioState and modifying it if the state has changed. Then after that the getActionsQValues is called which checks the modified state with the states in the HashMap. Only when the state is completely new to the HashMap (i.e. a unique combinations of properties that hasn't occurred in the HashMap yet) then it should be entered.

Comment: Short answer: you've broken the HashMap assumption that the hash code of a key won't change after you've added it then :) It's very odd to have a map with a key where equality is *only* based on a single `boolean` value anyway, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I changed my code a little by letting the update() method return a new MarioState and that seems to fix it. Thanks you very much! As for the equality, it's actually not only based on that boolean alone. That is just one property of the state, but that are many more properties a state can have (I only posted a simplified version of the state what I'm actually using). With a complete MarioState I have multiple properties with discrete values that can lead to hundreds of unique combinations (all will be stored in the HashMap). Equality is then based on all the properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you make an answer from your comment I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Done. Let me know if any more detail is required :)

Comment: BTW, there are only two meaningful values of `state`: either `stuck` is `true`, or `stuck` is `false`.  As such, is there any reason for using a `HashMap` rather than either a `float[2][]` or else two `float[]` variables--one for each case?

Comment: @supercat What I have shown you in my original post is a simplified version of `MarioState`. In reality `MarioState` has more properties where not all of them have to be boolean. I saw no point in providing the full code of `MarioState` as I could reproduce the problem with the simplified version depicted above. So in order to answer your question, yes I could have done that if I had only the `stuck` variable to take into account which can have two distinct values. But as I use more properties, I can end up going to 10000 distinct values with my more complete version of `MarioState`.

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt: Fair enough.  Perhaps something other than a `bool` might have been good for the property you kept, but no matter.  The key point as you've gathered is that a `HashTable` is entitled to assume that two objects whose hashes have been observed to be different will forevermore be different (more generally, I think it's allowed to assume that things which have been observed to be unequal via any means, are, though in most cases the hash code would be the only part that would matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hash code computation and equality comparison are both based on `stuck` - but that can change over time.

If you mutate an object after adding it as a key within a hash map, in such a way that the hash code changes, then the key will not be found when you later request it - because the hash code that was stored when the key was first added will no longer be the same as its current hash code.

Wherever possible, try to avoid using mutable objects as keys within a map (even a `TreeMap` which doesn't use the hash code would have the same problem if you changed the object in a way which would change relative ordering). If you *must* use mutable objects as keys within a map, you should avoid mutating them after adding them as keys.

Comment: Thanks for the information and for the tip! I'll look and see whether I can use immutable objects as keys instead (or avoid mutating them).